# Should we say "Do what you can't" or "Try what you can't"? What's the difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I've heard so ads say this quote:

> Do what you can't!

But later I'm thinking doesn't

> Try what you can't?

make more sense?

---

In my thought how can you say **Do what you can't** when you can't do it, if you **CAN** do it then the sentence doesn't makes sense, am I right?

If you look at **Try what you can't**, it looks more fine because you're encouraging somebody to try something new.

What do you think?

Am I correct with my view?

Also, is "**Do what you can't**" really a good sentence?

Comment: "Do what you can't" is perfectly grammatical, but is a contradiction. So it is pretty well meaningless except as marketing puff (where meaning is much less important than other aspects of language). The sentence doesn't make sense, so trying to make it make sense is a pointless exercise.

Comment: You said yourself: you saw in an **ad**. Ads don’t need to make logical sense, and this one clearly doesn’t.

Comment: @ColinFine Then how about **Try what you can't**?

Comment: *Try what you can't* is paradoxical in exactly the same way, because the omitted verb is assumed to be the same as the first: "Try what you can't try". If you can't try it, how can you try it? The thing about "Do what you can't" is that the advertised product **allows** you to do it. "Do what you would otherwise be unable to".

Comment: @AndrewLeach but why **Try what you can't** doesn't mean try what you can't do previously (and maybe you'll success)!

Comment: Because English doesn't work that way. If there is a verb omitted, the first choice for what it should be is the nearest verb still in the sentence which makes grammatical sense. If *try* is that verb still present, then *try* is taken to be the omitted word. It's **very** unusual to supply a word which is not already present.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Then what kind of words should we say to encourage someone to try/do something they've not/can't done before?

Comment: @Munucial Your question is drifting off its original subject. If you have another question, please ask it as a question — but be aware of the [rules for single-word-request questions](/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Since it is a contradiction I would rather say Do what you cannot do (in the present) or Do what you couldn't do. (past)

Comment: @Municial: in the context of the first sentence ("Do what you can't"), the second "Try what you can't" could be interpreted as "Try what you can't do", but on its own it probably wouldn't be. There is precedent for this: In _The Hunting of the Snark_, Lewis Carroll has the Bellman say "Do all the you know And try all that you don't", where the omitted verb is clearly "know".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface my answer by quoting Yoda,

"Do or do not, there is no try."

Having gotten that out of the way, let me say that language as we use it to communicate refers to the interlocutors' conceptualization of the world.

If someone says

> I can't pick up that 200-pound rock

but then proceeds to pick it up,  then his statement was still true at the time he said it. But his statement referred to his conceptualization of the world, which in this case did not align with reality.

So, if someone says

> Do pick up that 200-pound rock which you can't pick up

this is equivalent to

> Do pick up that 200-pound rock which you think/perceive you can't pick up.

And

> Do what you can't

simply means

> Do that which (what) you think you can't do, perhaps based on past experience, lack of confidence, ignorance of one's own abilities, etc.

Whatever it is, what you "can't do" is an erroneous perception of reality on "your" part.